# Displaying thumbnail image with plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using https://code.google.com/p/jquery-multifile-plugin/

I am trying to display the thumbnail of the image that was just selected with the following code:

```
$(function() {
    var doc = document;
    var oError = null;
    var oFileIn = doc.getElementById('file-upload');
    var oFileReader = new FileReader();
    var oImage = new Image();

    oFileIn.addEventListener('change', function () {
    alert("in");
    var oFile = this.files[this.files.length-1];
    //rest of the code
});
```

It works for the first image. When I try to add another the event isn't triggered, any suggestions?

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YaGuZ/1/

Comment: can you edit to recreate your problem

Comment: I don't see what part of that code displays a thumbnail. You said it works for the first image.

Comment: It could be because the name doesn't change for the Input Upload. EX: the text "No File Chosen" doesn't change b/c of the plugin. How can I forcefully try to change the name?